# Regex Match.NextMatch() for a string that is not consistent

Tags: c#, regex

I have this input string:

```
AT+CMGL=4\r\r\n+CMGL: 1,1,,155\r\nDFGDF312GF4J5457JG8J0JGKFJ345G67JHGFGHJ06FD45HJG86J958F4FHSGSDGFH23FJ24HGJH58G4D7D465HDK31HFDJCHGH8V7GD45231DFGF314J567V6GGK4GFJCHGKVGDJX765GHFCJX2X4537CCGHGK9VHJ3C2FJXJCGH\r\n+CMGL: 2,1,,126\r\nDFGDF312GF4J5457JG8J0JGKFJ345G67JHGFGHJ06FD45HJG86J958F4FHSGSDGFH23FJ24HGJH58G4D7D465HDK31HFDJCHGH8V7GD45231DFGF314J567V6GGK4GFJCHGKVGDJX765GHFCJX2X4537CCGHGK9VHJ3C2FJXJCGH\r\n+CMGL: 3,1,,148\r\nDFGDF312GF4J5457JG8J0JGKFJ345G67JHGFGHJ06FD45HJG86J958F4FHSGSDGFH23FJ24HGJH58G4D7D465HDK31HFDJCHGH8V7GD45231DFGF314J567V6GGK4GFJCHGKVGDJX765GHFCJX2X4537CCGHGK9VHJ3C2FJXJCGH\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
```

I would like to do a regex match on this one extracting two capture groups, and iterate through each match with the `NextMatch()` method.

I can achieve a partial match excluding the start (`AT+CMGL=4\r\r\n`) and end (`\r\nOK\r\n`) of this string which would be different for the first and last iteration.

This is the regex I use for the partial match I'm able to achieve:

```
\+CMGL: \d+,\d+,,(\d+)\\r\\n(.*?)\\r\\n
```

How would the correct syntax of the regex look like to get a complete match?

EDIT: I would like to capture the pdu length (155) and the pdu itself (nDFGDF312GF4J5457JG8J0JGKFJ345G67JHGFGHJ06FD45HJG86J958F4FHSGSDGFH23FJ24HGJH58G4D7D465HDK31HFDJCHGH8V7GD45231DFGF314J567V6GGK4GFJCHGKVGDJX765GHFCJX2X4537CCGHGK9VHJ3C2FJXJCGH) for each NextMatch().

Comment: and how can we guess what you **want** from that string..you need to specify that..also `regex` is used for `regularly` occurring pattern **not** `irregular` patterns!

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I have specified it in the EDIT section of the post. Well it's only the first and last part of the whole string that would not be the same, rest would be a regular occuring pattern. I could do some string formatting before using the regex to make it suit, but I thought if it was achievable with regex that would be a nicer/cleaner solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `regex` is correct..you just need to use the `singleline` mode with the regex

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(yourRegex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach(Match m in myRegex.Matches(yourText))
{
    m.Groups[1].Value;//pdu length
    m.Groups[2].Value;//pdu buffer
}
```